# Cubed Root - DDMathParser - Or in general?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm wondering how I can take the cubed root of a number in Xcode, or even better, if DDMathParser supports it. And *even* better, how i could take the x *th*  root.

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DDMathParser supports this:

```
NSNumber *cubeRoot = [@"nthroot(27, 3)" numberByEvaluatingString];
```

After this, `cubeRoot` will be `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode isn't a programming language...

But, how about taking the log of the number, dividing by three, and then taking the exponent of that result?  And replace 3 by X for the Xth root.

Or, use the pow() function and take the number to the 1/3 power (or 1/X power).

Comment: alright I knew I could do this, but I wasn't sure if there was an easier way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
double x,y,result;
```

Enter x and y values.  For example if you want to find out "cube" root of "5" then x and y will take the values as below. Using this one can find 5th root 6th root 100th root whatever you wish... But variables should be of type double .

```
x = 5;
y=3;
result = pow(x, 1.0/y);
```